# Unable to add 141.160.25.36/28, 141.160.4.51/29 in AWS security group Inbound rules

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-security-group

Unable to add 141.150.25.36/28, 141.140.4.51/29 in AWS security group Inbound rules. It says its not a valid range.

Comment: I managed to add them to a security group. Does it also give you the error if you create a new security group and try adding them? Please Edit your question and show your security group and the error message and/or tell us the exact steps you took.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein 141.140.4.51/29? Unless I have made a conversion error, 51₁₀ == 00110011₂ so its only possible valid prefix is /32.  The other CIDR has a similar problem, just less obvious at first glance.